# Set NSString Object, prepareForSegue through UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to set a dynamic NSString value each time a table cell is pressed in my app.  I am able to pass the variable to my custom UINavigationController with the code below -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *page = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setGrabPage: page];

}
```

The problem is that `grabPage` only gets set in the NavigationController, and not the top view displayed within the navigation controller.  How do I pass this value through to the top view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your destinationViewController is a UINavigationController, you should cast it into a UINavigationController and get the rootViewController of the navigation controller.

Cast it to the type of this first controller and you're good to go

**EDIT: Added sample code**

```objective-c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *page = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *)(nav.viewControllers[0]);
    [vc setGrabPage: page];
}
```