# why does my prepareForSegue Crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am trying to pass in IndexPath through a segue though a navigationController, but it crashes on line:

```
view.selectedAccount = self.selectedAccountRow;
```

thanks

```
-(IBAction)changeButtonPressed:(id)sender {

CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.accountTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.accountTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition]
self.indexPath = indexPath;
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

and

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    ViewController2 *view = [segue destinationViewController];
    view.selectedAccount = self.indexPath;
}
```

answer here: [Set NSString Object, prepareForSegue through UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187945/set-nsstring-object-prepareforsegue-through-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: what does the log say? why does it crash? btw: i do not think that you have to call super's implementation in prepareforsegue!

Comment: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: ok. that sounds like your ViewController2 class does not have a property called selectedAccount.

Comment: We need more info if you want any help, first of all where do `self.selectedAccountRow` gets defined?, second, does ViewController2 has a property named selectedAccount?

Comment: ViewController2.h has "@property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedAccount;"

Comment: ViewController.m has @property NSIndexPath *selectedAccountRow;

Comment: ok. then are you sure that segue.destinationviewcontroller really returns an instance of ViewController2?

Comment: You needn't to call the [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];!

Comment: yes it defiantly returns an instance of ViewController2

Comment: Don' post a partial error in your comments. Edit your question to show the actual complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I see many errors:

`self.selectedAccountRow` never gets defined, change to this:

```
-(IBAction)changeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
  CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.accountTableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.accountTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition]
  self.selectedAccountRow = indexPath;
}
```

When using [segue destinationViewController] you need to ensure that the class your assingning is the right one:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  ViewController2 *view = (ViewController2*)[segue destinationViewController];
  view.selectedAccount = self.selectedAccountRow;
}
```

There's no need to declare the as strong, as it is the default one, but it's recommender as it's easier to read, and it's a good coding practice.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedAccount;
```

You need to name better your classes and properties, if you declare a `viewController` subclass, the name should be self explanatory, maybe you can name it `detailViewController` instead on `viewController2`.

Also, you should consider using a 2-3 letters prefix for your classes, please read good obj-c practices in here:
[Objective-C Good practices](https://gist.github.com/soffes/812796)

Comment: i have hacked my code together, i work for a company so can't just copy the code. but it still crashed uses you advice

Comment: I had an error, I've just edited my answer, in the second code snippet I've changed my code to `view.selectedAccount = self.selectedAccountRow;` if this doesn't fix your error can you please gave us more details?, or the new error you are getting.

Comment: i have done that, still getting the "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Where did you called `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`? from the IB?

Comment: inside -(IBAction)changeButtonPressed:(id)sender

Comment: Can you write down the code you are using to do the segue?, I can't see it on your question. If you implementation of the segue is wrong, the segue.destinationViewController could be nil, or it could be another controller, if that is the case, you WILL get the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error because that other controller doesn't have the property you're trying to assign.

Comment: code to perform the segue `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetails" sender:self];
`

Comment: In the Storyboard, the destinationViewController has the right class assigned? (ViewController2)

Comment: yes, the segue works fine without passing the value and the class is assigned properly

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `view.selectedAccount = self.selectedAccountRow;` and see if `view` class is `ViewController2`

Comment: (lldb) po view.class gives UINavigationController presume this is why it is failing?

Comment: okay so its because the segue is to a navigation controller and then to ViewController2. Do i need to pass the variable to the navigationController and then to ViewController2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187945/set-nsstring-object-prepareforsegue-through-uinavigationcontroller for answer

Comment: Nice, I hope I helped somehow :).

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your view in IB and remove and instances where there is a yellow warning sign. Run and everything should work.